# How to use the Home key in guest VM and not in host VM?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora, guest-additions

Every time I press the Home key (Windows start key), my host OS (Fedora 29) detects it instead of the guest OS (Wind 10). I tried capturing mouse which screws everything. And all the other keys are detected by the guest except the host key (D'uh).

I am using the latest virtualbox version, with the expansion installed. And the machine has the guest additions installed.